# Does raw_input() stop an infinite while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop

There is a small code below containing of while-loop.

```
question = raw_input("How are you? > ")
state = True
number = 0
print "Hello"

while True:
    if question == "good":
        print "Ok. Your mood is good."
        state = False
        question_2 = raw_input("How are you 2? > ")
    elif question == "normal":
        print "Ok. Your mood is normal."
    elif question == "bad":
        print "It's bad. Do an interesting activity, return and say again what your mood is."
    else:
        print "Nothing"
```

If I type in *"normal"*, the program prints *Ok. Your mood is normal.* an infinite number of times.

But if I type in *"good"*, the program prints *Ok. Your mood is normal.* and prints the contents of question_2.

Why is the question in `question_2 = raw_input("How are you 2? > ")` not repeated an infinite number of times?

Is it reasonable to conclude that `raw_input()` stops any infinite while loop?

Comment: That sounds weird, are you sure it's `while True:` and not `while state:` ?

Comment: Yes. I have not  ended this code yet, state is for the other steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  It's not *stopping* the loop; it's actively blocking for input.  Once input is received, it will not be blocked anymore (and this is why you get infinite text from other selections); there is no blocking I/O in those branches.

The reason you're not getting a lot of text output from option 1 is due to the way it's being evaluated.  Inside of the loop, `question` never changes, so it's *always* going to evaluate to `"good"` and will continually ask you the second question<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1:  This is if it is indeed `while True`; if it's `while state`, it will stop iteration due to `state` being `False` on a subsequent run.</sup>

Comment: Thanks very much! Sorry for my mistakes in the text, english isn't my native language.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've answered "good, the value returned by the second raw_input will be stored in variable question_2 rather than question. So variable question never changes again, but will remain "good". So you'll keep hitting the second raw_input, no matter what you answer to it. It doesn't stop your loop, but rather pauses it until you answer. And I think you should also take a good look at the comment of Alfasin...

Answer (score 0):

You can stop an infinite loop by having an `else` or `elif` that uses a `break` for output. Hope that helps! :D

Example:

```
while True:
    if things:
        #stuff
    elif other_things:
        #other stuff
    #maybe now you want to end the loop
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

`raw_input()` does not break a loop. it just waits for input. and as your `question` is not overwritten by the second `raw_input()`, your `if` block will always end up in the `good` case.

a different approach:

```
answer = None

while answer != '':
    answer = raw_input("How are you? (enter to quit)> ")
    if answer == "good":
        print( "Ok. Your mood is good.")
    elif answer == "normal":
        print( "Ok. Your mood is normal.")
        # break ?
    elif answer == "bad":
        print( "It's bad. Do an interesting activity, return and say again what your mood is.")
        # break ?
    else:
        print( "Nothing")
        # break ?
```